# How to access an object's state without passing as parameter in method?

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a program for a college class that manages inventory, like through adding, removing, and renting items like DVD Players, furniture, and TV sets. My problem is, I want to get an object's saved state **without** passing in the object as an argument into the method to retrieve its state.

**ABCRentals.java**

```
private List<Integer> idNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
public String[] itemTypes2;

public boolean add(Item item)
{
    if (items.size() >= 300)
        return false;
    else
    {
        idNumbers.add(idNumbers.size() + 1);
        items.add(item);
        return true;
        // Code that adds item to itemTypes2 array (removed to avoid unnecessary code dump)
    }
}

public String[] getItemArray() {
   return itemTypes2;
}
```

**DVDPlayer.java**

```
public int getId(ABCRentals abc)
{
    String[] itemArray = abc.getItemArray();
    int id = Arrays.asList(itemArray).indexOf("DVDPlayer #" + Integer.toString(ID)) + 1;
    return id;
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ABCRentals abc = new ABCRentals();
    DVDPlayer item1 = new DVDPlayer();
    boolean flag = abc.add(item1);      
    int id = item4.getId(abc);
    System.out.println("Id: " + id);
}
```

Basically what I mean is, when I call the `getId()` method in the `Driver` class, I can't pass in the `abc` object as a parameter in order to get its state, as my professor requires me to have certain method signatures, with `getId()` in particular required to accept zero arguments. The `abc` object's state is changed when implementing the `add()` method and adding in an item. So, if I were to create a new instance of `ABCRentals` inside the `getId()` method, it would have an empty state as there'd be no items added in the object. Is there any way I can implicitly retrieve the `abc` object without passing it as a parameter? My code above works, but my method signature cannot be the way it is.

Comment: You should instead pass `abc` as a parameter to the constructor of `DVDPlayer` and assign it to a field in `DVDPlayer`. That way, you can access `abc` from inside your `getId()` method.

Comment: @JacobG. My constructor is also required to have zero args.

Comment: Then your only other option is to have `abc` be a `static` field so that you can access it from within `DVDPlayer`.

Comment: @JacobG. Would it be possible that you could give me an example through an answer and then I can accept it? Sorry, I'm pretty new to object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
DVDPlayer.java
    private ABCRentals mAbc;

    public void init(ABCRentals abc){
      mAbc = abc;
    }
```

call this init method to initialize your class instead and then call getId method.